# Why is there no "the" before "loss", "lack", "people", "lands" in these examples?

Tags: zero-article

Why is there no definite article before *loss* and *lack* in examples 1 & 2, before *people* in 3 & 4, and before *lands* in 4?

1. I'm suffering from loss of blood.
2. New parents are suffering from lack of sleep.
3. I know people who have seen ghosts.
4. I'm so sorry for people who live in lands where there are no May flowers.

In these sentences *loss*, *lack*, *people*, and *lands* aren't referring to general concepts, they are specified – so why we don't see definite articles before them?

Comment: Including the article in case #3 is syntactically fine, but *I know **the** people who have seen ghosts* strongly implies I know ***all*** of those people (who've seen some *particular* contextually-relevant ghosts, since it's unrealistic to suppose I know everyone who's *ever* seen a ghost). And so far as I'm concerned, with case #4 it's primarily a stylistic choice whether to include a determiner in contexts like *I feel sorry for [**the / those**] people stuck in tiny apartments during this Covid lockdown*, which has no real effect on meaning whichever choice is made.

Comment: You could optionally include "the" in 1, 2, and 4, though it might be a bit odd, depending on tone/context.  Including it in 3 implies that you know all the people who have ever seen ghosts.

Comment: @HotLicks: no, you can't include _the_ in 1 and 2. You can include _a_: a loss of blood, a lack of sleep.

Answer (score 1):

They actually are general concepts. They are not specified. Although we can infer there are particular things, the sentences do not refer to them. Instead, they each refer to an abstract quality.

For example, "people" does not refer to any particular people. It refers even to people in the future who you do not know--anyone who meets the criteria of "people who lives in lands where there are no Mayflowers", not a particular group who does.

Do you mean "new parents suffer from lack of sleep"?

Comment: One tricky example is when the phrase is in the subject, you would often use a determiner:  "The lack of sleep experienced by new parents causes stress".

Answer (score 0):

> 1. I'm suffering from loss of blood.

The word “loss” can be countable or uncountable. Here it is uncountable.

> 2. New parents are suffering from lack of sleep.

“New parents” is the plural of “A new parent” – plural nouns do not require a determiner.

> 3. I know people who have seen ghosts. –

“people” is the plural of “a person” – plural nouns do not require a determiner.

> 4. I'm so sorry for people who live in lands where there are no May flowers.

“lands” is the plural of “a land” – plural nouns do not require a determiner.

Comment: Plural and unclountable nouns don't require a determiner, but may have one.  Consider "The people who have seen ghosts are next door.